# Celery Supervisor Virtualenv can't find pip packages installed via github

Tags: python, django, celery, python-3.4, supervisord

Hello I am using supervisor with celery in order to run some tasks in a django web application.  Celery seems to be having an issue finding/resolving, models from packages that have been installed directly via github.

http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

As that states the packages are installed/cloned into a `<virtualenv>/src` directory.  I am wondering if I am missing something in my environment setup with `supervisord.conf` file such as the PYTHONPATH or something else to have these installed packages available.  I am getting a

> ValueError: Related model cannot be resolved

which does not seem to make sense as the  application as a whole is working fine with these packages.

**Versions**

Celery -  3.1.18

Supervisor - 3.0b2

**supervisord.conf**

```
[program:celeryd]
command=/home/path/to/virtualenv/celery worker -A moi --loglevel=info
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/celeryd.error.log
directory=/path/to/app
```

**The virtualenv looks structure looks like this**

```
virtualenv/
  - bin/
  - lib/
  - share/
  - src/github-installed-egg
```

**Error**

```
File "/home/ubuntu/moi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1600, in resolve_related_fields
raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
ValueError: Related model 'ndptc_core_courses.Course' cannot be resolved
```

The web application is running using nginx and uwsgi, and works fine .  The virtualenv setting in the uwsgi configuration file makes this work.  The model is a foreign key that is declared by name and not the model object itself.  Models that are from packages installed via pypi work fine as well its just those installed in the src folder that are causing the issue.

[described in django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Comment: Please  post what is the exact error you are getting, what is your config e.t.c

Comment: Did you manually install each VCS package or are they included in a requirements file? If so, can you show the lines from the requirements.txt file? Perhaps the relevant lines from `pip freeze` would also help.

Comment: They are a part of the requirements file    "-e git+h ttps://ndptc-admin@bitbucket.org/ndptc-admin/ndptc-core.git#egg=ndptc"  I put a space there in the http just so it wouldn't link.

Comment: Can you paste/link the full supervisord.conf file and relevant supervisor.d/*.conf files, as well as the output from `pip freeze` from inside your virtualenv and also from outside your vietualenv? The problem seems odd, I would start by looking at these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem, but a common scenario is to have your app installed under a virtualenv and supervisor installed directly on the host.

Under this scenario, you need to make sure that the celery version your are running is the one installed in your virtualenv and not a version that might be installed in the host's root environment.

As an example, lets assume your virtualenv is located at `/opt/virtualenvs/foo` and your supervisor program is configured at `/etc/supervisor.d/foo.conf`.

```
[program:foo]
command=/opt/virtualenvs/foo/bin/celery -A celery.conf worker
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was in the process of editing the question when you responded.  You are correct that supervisor is on the host and celery is on the virtualenv but I am calling the celery installed in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

You must "activate" virtualenv in `supervisor` config. To do this, add following line to Your app config:

```
environment=PATH="/opt/virtualenvs/foo/bin",VIRTUAL_ENV="/opt/virtualenvs/foo",PYTHONPATH="/opt/virtualenvs/foo/lib/python:/opt/virtualenvs/foo/lib/python/site-packages"
```